# Rollback doctrine:migrations with Deployer

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-migrations, php-deployer

I have a Symfony 3 application where I use [deployer](https://deployer.org) to deploy my application. Also I am using [Doctrine Migrations](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations) to migrate my database.

I use the [symfony3 recipe](https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/blob/master/recipe/symfony3.php).

When I run `dep deploy`, deployer migrates my database. However, when I run `dep rollback` it doesn't rollback the respective doctrine migrations.

I have searched through Google and Stackoverflow to find anybody solving this, but I can't seem to find anybody.

Do you have a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use backwards compatible migrations, this way no rollback is needed ever.

As it can result in a messy database, it's often a good idea to clean up the BC layers regularly. For instance:

1. Deploy B is deployed, it has a migration to not use a `full name` column, but instead split up in `first name` and `last name`. The `full name` column is still kept to be backwards compatible;
2. Assume B is unstable: You rollback to A. As there is still a fully working `full name` column, no migration rollbacks are needed;
3. Assume B is stable: When deploying Deploy C, a migration should be executed that first makes sure all `full name` values are split in `first name` and `last name` and then remove the `full name` column completely;
4. Assume deploy C is unstable: You rollback to B, as they both only use `full name`, no migration rollbacks are needed.

Comment: I like this approach, however it doesn't solve more complex problems. These are questions that came to my mind:

1. How to make a BC when you're changing relations between tables.
2. When somebody have a guarantee that something stable will be after a database change?

Comment: @Tomsgu DoctrineMigration maintains BC by allowing you to specify both `up` and `down` methods. It is up to developer however to be diligent and double-check that both methods are correct. For myself, I usually call them twice right after writing (`php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` and `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate prev`) to see if there are any issues. Also, my Continous Integration does the same checks just to be sure. When introducing backward-incompatible change, you should indicate it by using `$this->throwIrreversibleMigrationException()` inside `down` migration

Comment: Yeah of course it's possible with migrations. The thing is that we are talking about backwards compatible migrations without possibility to migrate to the previous version (rollback).